# Example of Twilio in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio

Well,I am getting difficulty finding out an example of Twilio message sending in Android.Could anybody site me an example along with what jar files do I need to import?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the reason you're having trouble finding that, is because sending messages on Android directly with Twilio is usually not recommended.

That is because to send an SMS message with Twilio, you will need an application Sid and an Auth Token, which are your credentials with Twilio. If you were to use the Java Library to send this SMS, it would mean your authentication keys are packaged with your application, which also means anyone who decompiles your application gets access to those keys and can use your account to do the same.

The way we usually recommend doing that is by creating a backend application, and then making an HTTP request to it. This way your keys live in the backend application, and you can configure it however you like, so even if you wanted the message to come from the device itself, you could just pass that to your backend application.

In [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) you will find how to send SMS messages using Twilio in all the most common programming languages.

Once you have one of those deployed, all you need to do is make an HTTP request to it from your app. There are lots of different libraries to help you doing that, but my favourite is Square's [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Here's how you could make an HTTP request to your backend app using it:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I am just using for learning purpose,its a cool thing

Comment: Yeah, it is awesome! Let me know if this helped you

Comment: Yes definitely... Thanks for pumping up my hope

Comment: Hah! Glad to have helped. Please make sure you mark the question as answered and come back if you have any more questions.

Comment: Marcos, can you show  me the full url sample to call (whcih will trigger to send sms)with account sid and auth taken, bit confused with the url.I need only the sample url

Comment: I've replied to your other question with more details about how to do that

Comment: I am using this :https://ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts.json ,getting unauthorised

Comment: Like I said on your other question, you shouldn't be trying to git Twilio directly, but have a backend application for that. Passing the Account Sid and Auth Token via the app poses a serious security risk

Comment: Thanks for that and I got succeeded in calling the rest api. deeply Appreciated